# Who are some (relatively) modern "platonists" with respect to aesthetics/philosophy of art?

Tags: aesthetics, art, platonism

I'm interested in discovering post-Enlightenment to contemporary thinkers who discuss art in terms of form and beauty, and imitation vs "true forms."

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.dartmouth.edu/~matc/math5.geometry/unit6/unit6.html This may be helpful.